# R: Interdependently connecting lists in Shiny's ui

Tags: r, string, shiny, subset

I'm working on a simple Shiny App and I would like to provide end-users with an opportunity to select a geaography from list that correspond to a vector:

```
> lst.geos
 [1] Geo A Geo B Geo C Geo D 
 [5] Geo E Geo F Geo G
```

I'm working to connect my list, so if the **Geo A** is selected in the first list, I would like for the geography to *disappear* from the second list, as in the context of this particular application there is no point in selecting the same geograpy twice. The extract from my `ui.R` looks like that:

**ui.R**

```
h4("Geographies"),
# Provide selections for local authorities
selectInput("selectGeoOne", label = h5("Geography 1"), 
            choices = lst.geos, selected = 1),
selectInput("selectGeoTwo", label = h5("Geography 2"), 
            choices = lst.geos[lst.geos != input$selectGeoOne],
            selected = 2)
```

I'm simply trying to subset the second vector with use of `lst.geos[lst.geos != input$selectGeoOne]` but I'm getting the error message: `Error in NextMethod("[") : object 'input' not found`. I'm guessing the problem lies in Shiny's scoping rules. Hence my question, how can I properly reference `ui.R` elements within the `ui.R`?

Comment: Have a look at `?updateSelectInput` - I think that is what you need for your problem.

Comment: This should work, I was hoping that maybe there is a less tedious solution but why not.